# LaTeX article style - How to pause text display?

Tags: pdftex, overlays, pause

I cannot believe I cannot find the answer by googling;8-)

The issue: I have LaTeX article I process with PdfLaTeX. The text is a question with multiple-choice options. Currently, the correct answer is given on the same page, under the question and multiple-choice options.
I would like to have a version of the LaTeX file where the text is "paused" after the question and itemized list of possible answers and the user needs to hit <kbd>return</kbd> to reveal the answer. Obviously, I don't want to go through the trouble of duplicating every page, with one having a question with multiple options and the next one having a question + multiple options + correct answer.

I was thinking I could find a simple solution, like inserting just one command before the answer, something like `\pause` in `beamer`. But I could not find the solution!

Comment: article has no commands for interaction. Why not use beamer?

Comment: `\pause` in `beamer` does exactly what you say you don't want: it duplicates the "page, with one having a question with multiple options and the next one having a question + multiple options + correct answer."  Or are you looking for a command that will do that for you?

Comment: Yes, but my file is a LaTex article style file: \documentclass[40pt]{article} I don't want a beamer style pdf output, and I would like to use emacs editor to put in just one command before every answer. I am interested in the pdf output and would like to do minimum editing/typing in the original LaTeX file.

Comment: So you are saying that it is not possible to do with the "article" style"?

Comment: nothing is impossible but it will be easier to style beamer to be more like article than to implement this beamer feature in article. `[40pt]` ??